# Updating a PHP variable depending on which link was clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I display a page with a list of users using this loop:

```
foreach ($mytaxonomies as $mytaxonomy) :  setup_postdata($mytaxonomy);
  echo $mytaxonomy->name; // print the name of the user
  echo '<a>Send email</a>';
endforeach;
```

the object `$mytaxonomy` contains many values like the email of the current user in `$mytaxonomy->email`

Clicking on the  link (Send email) shows a modal overlay with a form to send an email to that user.
The form sends the mail to the email address specified in the variable `$to` but I'm not able to assign the `$mytaxonomy->email` to that variable (depending on which link was clicked).

I need a thing like

```
<?php $to = $mytaxonomies[...]->email; ?>
```

where `$mytaxonomies[...]->email` changes everytime I click on a different user (because obviously each user have a different email).

**EDIT:** $mytaxonomies is the array that containes all the users with their infos

```
print_r($mytaxonomies);

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => John Doe
            [slug] => john-doe
            [email] => johndoe@email.com
            [age] => ...
            [phone] => ...
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [name] => Jane Doe
            [slug] => jane-doe
            [email] => jdoe77@converge.con
            [age] => ...
            [phone] => ...
        )

    ...
)
```

Comment: what are you storing in `$mytaxonomies` and what is `$mytaxonomies`

Comment: edited the first post

Answer (score 1):

Send the e-mail using ajax. Or in another page. You can't set a php variable in a page after the page is loaded.

Ajax example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
  var data = 'mail=' + $(this).prop('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    url: 'sendmail.php',
    success: function(){
      alert('mail sent');
    }
  )};
)};
```

PHP:

```
<?
foreach ($mytaxonomies as $mytaxonomy) :  setup_postdata($mytaxonomy);
  echo $mytaxonomy->name; // print the name of the user
  echo "<a href='{$mytaxonomy->email}'>Send email</a>";
endforeach;
?>
```

In sendmail.php you can get the variable mail with POST
example: `$to = $_POST["mail"];`

The HTML form:

```
<form id="myform" style="display:none" action="sendmail.php">
 ...
 <input name="to">
 <input name="from">
 ...
</form>
```

The jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
  var mail = $(this).prop("href");
  $("#myform").show();
  $('#myform input[name="to"]').val(mail);
});
```

You will no longer need ajax. the form will send you to sendmail.php.
Note: "..." are the rest of your form :)

Comment: what JOE LEE answered is an example of sending in another page. And with ajax is the same thing but with ajax. I will edit my answer...

Comment: I hope that this will help you

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it. Notice: the last two couple of brackets must be inverted. And I don't get what means the brackets in href -> {$mytaxonomy->email}. maybe you mean 
`<a href='" . $mytaxonomy->email . "'>`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I haven't tested the code. It's just blind written :)

Comment: If you want to make it secure, you should check the source where the request comes from. For example if the admin is the one who sends these e-mails then you should check that if the logged user is the admin. If you used a framework it would be more secure.

Comment: sure, but in my case anyone could want to send an email to an user because it's a "public" page, no user registration. then in this case is there a way to increase security?

Comment: there's a problem: when I click on the link it must be open a modal with the form, indeed with your code it goes directly to send the mail. it's a 2 step procedure: 1) click the link that open the form and set the email of the user 2) compile the form and click Submit botton to send the mail. your code do both without the time to compile the form. right?

Comment: If you want to display a form when clicked on a button you can have that form hidden on the page and when it's clicked just show the form. I will edit my answer...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28817/discussion-between-fred-k-and-paul-moldovan)

Answer (score -1):

!!!!!dont trust any value from client side

```
<?
foreach ($mytaxonomies as $mytaxonomy) :  setup_postdata($mytaxonomy);
  echo $mytaxonomy->name; // print the name of the user
  echo "<a href='send_mail.php?mail={$mytaxonomy->email}'>Send email</a>";
endforeach;
?>
```

send_mail.php

```
<?
$mail = $_GET['mail'];
mail($mail, 'My Subject', 'message');
?>
```

UPDATE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
<?
foreach ($mytaxonomies as $mytaxonomy) :  setup_postdata($mytaxonomy);?>
<form  action="send_mail.php" method="post">
<? echo $mytaxonomy->name;?> 

<input type="hidden" name="mail" value="<?echo $mytaxonomy->email?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
  <? endforeach;?>
```

send_mail.php

```
<?
//just for demo send mail function, dont copy and use
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
mail($mail, 'My Subject', 'message');
?>
```

Comment: @STTLCU: you mean that this method is not the better one? is ajax method (see Paul Moldovan's answer) more secure?

Comment: the problem is the second part of the script, the one which sends an email. It's easily exploitable if i know the url i can send thousands of unwanted emails... I know it's just a snippet, but at least put a disclaimer about security on it because new PHP users may overlook it

Comment: The security flaw is still here, do you really think that POST variables and hidden input fields aren't manipulable?

Comment: sorry, but probleme here is that the name of the page that sends email is visible? in this case, it's visible also in the Ajax method posted by Paul Moldovan

Comment: ajax or web form is same on security

Comment: no, the problem is that you get the email address and send an email to it, without any security control about WHO asked your script to send an email. Sure, you assume that it's the link in the earlier page, but it's not guaranteed, as i demonstrated above. I'm just asking to put a comment-notice on the send_mail.php snippet about this, to warn newbie PHP programmers that read this answer, otherwise they may blindly copy and paste the code above without clues about the dangers.

Comment: @STTLCU: THX , i will put a comment-notice next time, u a right

Comment: @STTLCU: then what is a secure way to do this (if there is one)?

Comment: it depends a lot on the rest of the application, I just wouldn't leave a script that can send email freely accessible by the general public.

Comment: I understand your point but all the web uses the contact forms, also notable sites... then are they all unsecure?

Comment: add Verification Code for robot , and compare post[mail] with $mytaxonomy->email before send mail